# How do I start and stop youtube videos created with the youtube iframe API?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I've created a function that wraps around YT.Player. It injects youtube videos into a document:

```
function swGetYoutubeVids ( elById, videoId ) {
            var playerName = elById ;
            window.playerName = new YT.Player( elById, {
                height : '',
                width: '',
                videoId : videoId,
                playerVars: {
            enablejsapi : 1,
            modestbranding : 1,
            origin : playerOrigin,
            showinfo : 0
        },

 }) ;
```

It works: A new video is created if I do `swGetYoutubeVids('player_1', 'vha-Swtnj-U')`

The function also creates a variable on window, so I can control the player. Well, at least that's the idea.

In the call above, window.player_1 gets created. I can confirm this by testing for the existence of window.player_1 from my browsers console.

However, window.player_1.playVideo() doesn't work.
According to the API docs, that call should start the video playing. Instead I get 'playVideo is not a function'.

So how do I actually play the video?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution -> https://plnkr.co/edit/Tb0YpAtsiruK7H63wabj?p=preview

Loading the script is asynchronous. After initializing the player, you need to link events.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="player_1"></div>

<div class="wrap" style="display: none">
    <button id="play" onclick="playVideo()">play</button>
    <button id="pause" onclick="pauseVideo()">pause</button>
</div>

<script>
    var player;

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){
        swGetYoutubeVids('player_1', 'vha-Swtnj-U');
    }

    function swGetYoutubeVids(elById, videoId ) {
        player = new YT.Player(elById, {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: videoId,
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady
            },
            playerVars: {
                enablejsapi : 1,
                modestbranding : 1,
                //origin : playerOrigin,
                showinfo : 0
            },
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(){
        // here is player ready
        console.info(player);
        document.getElementsByClassName('wrap')[0].style.display = 'block';
    }

    function playVideo() {
        player.playVideo()
    }

    function pauseVideo() {
        player.pauseVideo()
    }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If so, you can mark the question as being answered.